# Rvest returning table containing NAs

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-table, rvest

I am trying to scrape data from a table using the Rvest package, but the table is coming back filled with NAs and missing all but the first row.

How can I solve this?

```
Source <- "https://www.viewbase.com/bitfinex_long_short_position"

Longs <- read_html(Source)%>%html_node(xpath='/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table')%>%
html_table(fill=TRUE)%>% as.data.frame()

Longs

     Long Position 24H Change Short Position 24H Change % Long vs. Short NA NA NA NA
1 NA            NA         NA             NA         NA               NA NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to use RSelenium to get the exact same output that you see on the webpage. However, you might also get most of the information from json file available on the webpage.

```
jsonlite::fromJSON('https://api.viewbase.com/margin/bfx_long_short_now') %>%
  dplyr::bind_rows()

#  BTCUSD BTCUST ETHUSD ETHUST  ETHBTC USTUSD XRPUSD  XRPBTC BABUSD
#   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 58323  5.82e4 4.08e3  4078. 7.01e-2 1.00e0 1.57e0 2.69e-5   252 
#2 58100  5.81e4 3.88e3  3880. 6.68e-2 1.00e0 1.52e0 2.62e-5   252 
#3 31557. 2.30e3 1.93e5 21972. 3.62e+5 3.72e5 5.07e7 2.54e+7  8843.
#4 31547. 2.30e3 1.87e5 21944. 4.05e+5 1.41e6 5.11e7 2.53e+7  8843.
#5   559. 1.97e2 2.43e5   442. 1.02e+4 9.09e6 9.71e6 1.71e+7 15050.
#6   601. 3.81e1 2.46e5   598. 9.35e+3 1.34e5 9.97e6 1.73e+7 15050.
# … with 27 more variables: BABBTC <dbl>, LTCUSD <dbl>, LTCBTC <dbl>,
#   EOSUSD <dbl>, EOSBTC <dbl>, ETCUSD <dbl>, ETCBTC <dbl>,
#   BSVUSD <dbl>, BSVBTC <dbl>, XTZUSD <dbl>, XTZBTC <dbl>,
#   ZECUSD <dbl>, ZECBTC <dbl>, LEOUSD <dbl>, LEOUST <dbl>,
#   DSHUSD <dbl>, DSHBTC <dbl>, IOTUSD <dbl>, IOTBTC <dbl>,
#   NEOUSD <dbl>, NEOBTC <dbl>, OMGUSD <dbl>, OMGBTC <dbl>,
#   XLMUSD <dbl>, XLMBTC <dbl>, XMRUSD <dbl>, XMRBTC <dbl>
```